# for loop ends with 'none' value

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, if-statement

My code is performing file creation using dataframe rows being put through a function in a loop.
When every row has been processed the loop returns `None` which prevents my entire template from being fully injected with data.

How to stop that loop once all data has been processed to avoid getting `None` as the last result?

```
def template_input_col(df,i):

    col = df['ColumnName'].iat[i]
    dt_type = df['SSISType_src'].iat[i]
    dt_lngh = df['DataTypeLength_src'].iat[i]
    dt_prc = df['DataTypePrecision_src'].iat[i]
    dt_scl = df['DataTypeScale_src'].iat[i]

    input_columns = f'''\
    <inputColumn 
        refId="Package\DFT\DST.Inputs[DST Input].Columns[{col}]"
        cachedDataType="{dt_type}"
        cachedName="{col}"
        cachedLength="{dt_lngh}"
        cachedPrecision="{dt_prc}"
        cachedScale="{dt_scl}"
        externalMetadataColumnId="Package\DFT\DST.Inputs[DST Input].ExternalColumns[{col}]"
        lineageId="Package\DFT\SRC.Outputs[SRC Output].Columns[{col}]" />'''

    if dt_type in {'str','wstr','bytes'}:
        input_columns = re.sub(r'\s*cachedPrecision=".*"', '', input_columns)
        input_columns = re.sub(r'\s*cachedScale=".*"', '', input_columns)
    elif dt_type in {'numeric'}:
        input_columns = re.sub(r'\s*cachedLength=".*"', '', input_columns)
    elif dt_type in {'decimal' , 'dbtime2' , 'dbTimeStamp2' , 'dbTimeStampoffset'}:
        input_columns = re.sub(r'\s*cachedLength=".*"', '', input_columns)
        input_columns = re.sub(r'\s*cachedPrecision=".*"', '', input_columns)
    else:
        #input_columns = input_columns
        input_columns = re.sub(r'\s*cachedLength=".*"', '', input_columns)
        input_columns = re.sub(r'\s*cachedPrecision=".*"', '', input_columns)
        input_columns = re.sub(r'\s*cachedScale=".*"', '', input_columns)

    return input_columns

def output_input_col():
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if not pd.isna(row['DataTypeName_src']) and not pd.isna(row['DataTypeName_dst']):
            return template_input_col(df,idx)

print(output_input_col())
```

Once data is processed it has to injected with below:

```
line = line.replace('<DST_Input_Columns_Placeholder>',  output_input_col())
```

Expected result must retain the format of:

```
<inputColumn
                        refId="Package\DFT\DST.Inputs[DST Input].Columns[created_at]"
                        cachedDataType="dbTimeStamp"
                        cachedName="created_at"
                        externalMetadataColumnId="Package\DFT\DST.Inputs[DST Input].ExternalColumns[created_at]"
                        lineageId="Package\DFT\SRC.Outputs[SRC Output].Columns[created_at]" />
<inputColumn
                        refId="Package\DFT\DST.Inputs[DST Input].Columns[updated_at]"
                        cachedDataType="dbTimeStamp"
                        cachedName="updated_at"
                        externalMetadataColumnId="Package\DFT\DST.Inputs[DST Input].ExternalColumns[updated_at]"
                        lineageId="Package\DFT\SRC.Outputs[SRC Output].Columns[updated_at]" />
<inputColumn
                        refId="Package\DFT\DST.Inputs[DST Input].Columns[deleted_at]"
                        cachedDataType="dbTimeStamp"
                        cachedName="deleted_at"
                        externalMetadataColumnId="Package\DFT\DST.Inputs[DST Input].ExternalColumns[deleted_at]"
                        lineageId="Package\DFT\SRC.Outputs[SRC Output].Columns[deleted_at]" />
```

Comment: There's no `return` statement in `output_input_col()`. What are you expecting to print?

Comment: There may be some confusion. Your function isn't returning ```None``` because of what may or may not be the last value used in the ```for``` loop. It returns ```None``` because it has no explicit ```return``` statement.

Comment: `template_input_col` returns a string, but you're not doing anything with it in your `for` loop. So all this code really does nothing.

Comment: `return` does the job but I'm getting only last set of data injected even though there are 1+ rows in the dataframe

Comment: `return` ends the function, so it stops the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `if` condition is never true for any rows of the dataframe, the function never executes the `return` statement, so it will return `None`.

When the condition is true, the function stops at that row of the dataframe, since `return` ends the function.

If you want a list of all the templates, append them to a list, and return that after the loop.

```
def output_input_col():
    results = []
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if not pd.isna(row['DataTypeName_src']) and not pd.isna(row['DataTypeName_dst']):
            results.append(template_input_col(df,idx))
    return results
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar! This will work but one thing I need to retain is the structure of each block that is created while processing the template. Creating a list which I can convert back to string crashes my established formatting. I updated my case with what is happening later.

Comment: I don't understand how you expect that to work. What do you expect `output_input_col()` to return so you can use it in `replace()`? The second argument must be a string.

Comment: I played around and `"\n".join(output_input_col())` returns the desired result :) `output_input_col()` was to return n-templates filled with data from dataframe per row in a specified format.